# SQL subqueries PostgreSQL 12

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgres-12

I'm having a table similar to this:

| first | last | date | pos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john | doe | 18-03-2021 |  |
| harris | potter |  | 10-06-2021 |
| john | doe | 10-05-2021 |  |
| harris | potter | 14-06-2021 |  |
| jessica | potter | 14-06-2021 |  |
| kermit | foster |  |  |

The use case is as follow:

- The pos column correspond to a positive covid test
- The date column correspond to the vaccination date

To be elligible for a covid certificate, some one must either:

- Been tested positive and have got 1 vaccine
- Have receive 2 vaccine

I'm trying to write a query that return me:
totalDose, totalRequieredDose

For exemple:

- If he has tested positive, the totalRequiredDose is 1 and if he has got 1 vaccine, he is elligible. As such, for Harry Potter, totalDoses=1 and totalRequieredDoses=1 and is elligible
- If he has not been tested positive, the totalRequiredDose is 2 and if he has got 2 vaccines, he is elligible. As such, for John Doe, totalDoses=2 and totalRequieredDoses=2 and is elligible

| first | last | totalDoses | totalRequieredDoses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john | doe | 2 | 2 |
| harris | potter | 1 | 1 |
| jessica | potter | 1 | 2 |
| kermit | foster | 0 | 2 |

As Jessica Potter have a vaccine and no pos date, she must have 2 vaccines.
So the value 1/2
And Kermit foster have no pos value, he is 0/2
Etc.

I'm scratching my head to write a query (or pl/sql) that could return me such table.

Could someone give me some hints ?

Comment: Your second example seems about wrong person. It's confusing readers a bit

Comment: @Serg I have corrected it. Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can aggregate by first and last name.  The total doses is simply the count of non `NULL` vaccination dates.  For the total required number of doses, we can start with a value of 2.  This value can then be offset by 1 assuming there exists a non `NULL` date for the `pos` column, indicating that a given person tested positive at some point.

```sql
SELECT
    first,
    last,
    COUNT(date) AS totalDoses,
    2 - (COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE pos IS NOT NULL) > 0)::int AS totalRequieredDoses
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    first,
    last
ORDER BY
    COUNT(date) DESC,
    first,
    last;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm testing right now. Will revert shortly